# Complex Conditional Formatting Scenario

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, counting

Thank you in advance for whatever help you may be able to provide.

**Purpose/Scope**

Analyzing the effectiveness of retail store renovations and relocations.

**Existing Material**

I have many slices or views, but let's assume there is only one.

The back-end looks like this. Please note that empty cells will still have a formula in them as they are being populated from a data dump.

[Back-End](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aETRl.jpg)

The front-end looks like this and is populated with an 'Averageifs' formula, simplified example is below. "CompStores" is a named data range.

=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(CompStores[Growth Year 2],CompStores[Action],$A1),"")

[Front-End](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF6tu.jpg)

Just for clarity, the counting table (if needed) would look like this. Hopefully this project will not need a counting table, especially considering switching "averageifs" to "countifs" cannot easily be done by a search+replace because countifs has less arguments.

[Counts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrGev.jpg)

**The Task**

•   Highlight each cell in the front-end based on how many observations there are with the purpose of knowing how confident we are in that growth %.
•   The counting system I would like to use in real life is under 5 observations = red, 5 to 9 = yellow, 10 or above = green.

Here is an example output based on the count and colours I will use in real life.

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMBH2.jpg)

Please help me, I really don't want to have to do this by hand lol. Thanks to anyone who even attempts to help!!!

Comment: "*Highlight each cell in the front-end based on how many observations there are*". Based on how many observations of *what*? Example calculations and outputs would be helpful here.

Comment: "Based on how many observations of what?" I am counting the number or renovations or relocations that happened long enough ago to appear in that cell's growth year. Just added a sample output. Can you please remove your downvote so more people might respond?

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter. I'll take a look at your sample output.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have several conditions for conditional formatting, I always prefer to non-conditionally (permanently) format the cells with the most complicated condition and then use subsequent conditional formatting rules to "override" the base formatting.

In this case, since yellow is the most complicated condition (since yellow falls within a range and has two bounds, as opposed to red and green which just have a single bound), I permanently formatted the entire range (`B2:E3`) as yellow and then made two conditional formatting rules (one for red and one for green) to override the yellow base formatting.

See below screenshots of simplified versions of your data.

[image]

[image]

[image]